# Little confusion in drawing Feynmam diagram

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, scattering, antimatter, feynman-diagrams

If the arrows of both the outgoing solid lines of the Feynman diagram corresponding to the Bhabha scattering of $e^+$ and $e^-$ are just reversed, will it not describe the same thing? Doesn't both imply the same, namely that $e^+$ and $e^-$ comes out finally?

It will also give the same amplitude right? I hope this diagram I can draw in either of the ways, no problem. It does not matter whether I draw $e^+$ line above and $e^-$ line below or vice-versa. Am I right? But the books generally draw, $e^-$ as the upper outgoing line, if they use $e^-$ as the upper incoming line. Is this really necessary? What will go wrong if I draw $e^+$ as the upper line and $e^-$ as the lower line on the outgoing side when I use the opposite for the incoming lines?

I could not copy and paste any diagram, so the question size has become long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There are two possible Feynman graphs for Bhabha scattering at tree level.
>   I have shown them below.

[image]

> Are you asking what will go wrong if these two are modified like shown below.

[image]

> > If this is what you are asking then the only thing that we should be
> >     concerned about is the conservation of charge at each vertex point.

We can clearly see that the charge is not conserved for the modified graph on the 
left. So we cannot draw it that way.

But the modified graph for the annihilation process (right one) is consistent
with the conservation of charge so its OK to draw it that way.